# Wordpress admin area: select box with 12.000+ options

Tags: custom-field, admin, metabox, select

I have a custom post type that in admin area has a select custom meta box with 12.000+ options. So, in some cases, WordPress show an error message like memory exhausted.

Which could be a good troubleshooting to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Don’t know what you expect to find by troubleshooting. 12000 options, presumably loaded from a database, is just too much to load at once. You need to find an alternative UI for loading these options.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly. I asking for suggestions to find those alternatives that you talk

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot would be to use a javascript-enhanced selectbox like select2 and an ajax-action to search for options. Right now, i don't have the time to write actual pseudo-code for you, but i guess this link should give you the direction: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax